# How to display wireless temp and humidity values in same messagebox at same time?

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino

This my first try in creating the desktop application in python.
I am trying to receive the values from [Wireless Temperature sensor](https://ncd.io/long-range-iot-wireless-temperature-humidity-sensor-product-manual/) using serial package and with the help of Tkinter package in python

I am able to test value in the message box

Is there any sample which helps me to show readings of temperature in degrees Celsius, Fahrenheit, Humidity in the same message box?

For Wireless Sensor interface with Arduino I am using code:

```c
uint8_t data[29];
int k = 10;
int i;

void setup()
{
    Serial1.begin(9600);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("ncd.io IoT Arduino wireless temperature Humidity sensor");
}

void loop()
{
    if (Serial1.available())
    {
        data[0] = Serial1.read();
        delay(k);
        if(data[0]==0x7E)
        {
            while (!Serial1.available());
            for (i = 1; i< 29; i++)
            {
                data[i] = Serial1.read();
                delay(1);
            }
            if(data[15]==0x7F)  /////// to check if the recive data is correct
            {
                if(data[22]==1)  //////// make sure the sensor type is correct
                {
                    float humidity = ((((data[24]) * 256) + data[25]) /100.0);
                    int16_t cTempint = (((unit16_t)(data[26])<<8)| data[27];
                    float cTemp = (float)cTempint /100.0;
                    float fTemp = cTemp * 1.8 + 32;
                    float battery = ((data[18] * 256) + data[19]);
                    float voltage = 0.00322 * battery;

                    Serial.print("Sensor Number  ");
                    Serial.println(data[16]);
                    Serial.print("Sensor Type  ");
                    Serial.println(data[22]);
                    Serial.print("Firmware Version  ");
                    Serial.println(data[17]);
                    Serial.print("Relative Humidity :");
                    Serial.print(humidity);
                    Serial.println(" %RH");
                    Serial.print("Temperature in Celsius :");
                    Serial.print(cTemp);
                    Serial.println(" C");
                    Serial.print("Temperature in Fahrenheit :");
                    Serial.print(fTemp);
                    Serial.println(" F");
                    Serial.print("ADC value:");
                    Serial.println(battery);
                    Serial.print("Battery Voltage:");
                    Serial.print(voltage);
                    Serial.println("\n");
                    if (voltage < 1)
                    {
                        Serial.println("Time to Replace The Battery");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (i = 0; i< 29; i++)
                {
                    Serial.print(data[i]);
                    Serial.print(" , ");
                    delay(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Earlier I have tested this sample as mentioned below:

It only displays the data which displays the data with the serial command

```
Serial.println("HELLO");
```

instead of command

```
Serial.print("HELLO");
```

Another Issue is that it displays only one message at a time, but I want all the messages of serial data to be displayed in one `messagebox` at the same time only

I have made this sample for testing

for Arduino:

```c
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println("HELLO");
    Serial.println("HELLO1");
    Serial.println("HELLO2");
    delay(1000);
}
```

For Python Code:

```python
import serial
import json
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox

top = tkinter.Tk()

ard = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600);

def helloCallBack():
    k = ard.readline().decode('ascii');
    if (len(k)>0):
        print (k);
        size = len(k);
        #print (k[0:size-2]);
        print (size);
        messagebox.showinfo('Message From Arduino',k[0:size-2]+'\n'+str(size))

B = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Hello", command = helloCallBack)
B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Any advice here will be a great help.

Comment: Is there some way to check from Python if an Arduino message data is available and ready to be read? If there is, you could set up something to periodically check for this and update the tkinter GUI display accordingly.

Comment: Accumulate all `data` into **one** `record` and do only **one** `Serial.print(record);`.

Comment: Hi @stovfl, Can you share me sample or modification in test code which has mentioned in the post? Right now I am receiving the data as [ Hello\r\n <next line> Hello2\r\n<next line> Hello3\r\n], I need to slice these message and store it in python variables

Comment: Are you familiar with [Serialize structured data with json](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#index-1)? You should be able to build a `JSON` on the `Arduino` side.